# PHP Creating select box starting from current month

Tags: php

I have a select box with the following values ( months of the year ):

```
<label for="select_month">Month: </label>
<select id="select_month" name="month">
<option value="01">01</option>
<option value="02">02</option>
<option value="03">03</option>
<option value="04">04</option>
<option value="05">05</option>
<option value="06">06</option>
<option value="07">07</option>
<option value="08">08</option>
<option value="09">09</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="11">11</option>
<option value="12">12</option>
</select>
```

What I would like to achieve is to get with PHP the current month, and make that as default-selected option in my select box.

How can I do that with a clean code?

Comment: nothing actually. Whatever comes to my mind looks bad.

Comment: Post what you've tried. This isn't a site to request free coding. People are willing to help, but you have to make an effort.

Comment: Judging from your other questions you might need to get a basic PHP book or do some online tutorials...

Comment: ok, I stand correct, I guess people are willing to puke out answers. It's funny, if this question was asked without the code sample (which, in this case, is irrelevant) it would have been down-voted and closed by now. :)

Comment: @Paul - While I agree that he should've actually tried some different methods (outside of his mind) first, some people learn best by seeing some example code :)

Comment: @Batfan - Agreed. That's why I do research and find sample code before I ask the question here. If, after I've tried and still can't get it to work, I'll ask here. He, under his own admission, didn't attempt to solve the problem first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++)
(
    $month = ($i < 10) ? '0'.$i : $i;
    echo '<option value="'.$month.'"';
    if ($i == date("n")) echo ' selected="selected"';
    echo '>'.$month.'</option>';
)
```

I can't test this as I'm on my phone, but that should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps something like this?

```
<select name="month">
<?php foreach(range('1', '12') as $m) : ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $m; ?>" <?php if (date('n') == $m) { echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?>>
        <?php echo $m ?>
     </option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my two cents:

```
<label for="select_month">Month: </label>
<select id="select_month" name="month">

<?php

 for($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) {
  $isCurrentMonth = ($i == intVal(date("m"))) ? 'true': 'false';
  echo "<option value=\"$i\" selected=\"$isCurrentMonth\">$i</option>\n";
 }

?>

</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Uses a similar structure to Pratt's answer, but uses the double-digit month values (like you had in your example).  It uses date('m') instead of date('n') and since there doesn't appear to be any way to get leading zeros in PHP range, I used an array.

```
<select name="month">
<?php foreach(array('01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08','09','10','11','12') as $m) : ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $m; ?>" <?php if (date('m') == $m) { echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?>>
        <?php echo $m ?>
     </option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<option value="01" <?php echo (1 == date("n") ? 'selected="selected"' : ''); ?>>01</option>
```

This will have to be done for every option - a for loop might be nice in this situation.

Comment: What's a loop? how do I do that? Sorry I am new to such things.